# Some examples of rigidity lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

We say that a category with finite products obeys the rigidity lemma if any morphism $X \times Y \rightarrow Z$
that is constant along some point $y \in Y$ is globally independent of $X$. Such categories have remarkable features - all group objects are abelian, all pointed maps between them are homomorphism, group structures are unique.

The canonical example is the category of proper smooth varieties, but I wonder if there are any other interesting ones (both toy and real ones will make me grateful).

EDIT:
By a point I mean the morphism from terminal object, by constant map - factoring through terminal map, by independent - factoring through projection.

Comment: Can you please specify the meaning of "point" and "globally independent" in the case of an arbitrary category with finite products (and add it to the question body)?

Comment: Sure, I've filled the definitions to the question

Comment: More details you can read on nlab page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/abelian+variety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three examples are the category of monoids, the category of groups, and (although this is close to your original example of abelian varieties) for any commutative ring $R$ the category of $R$-modules.

Comment: These categories have a zero object, so there is just point anyway (with the author's definition).

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot!